How do I reference meshes in Rhino Python for a boolean difference operation?
I have 2 meshes and I can manually perform a boolean difference on the 2 in the GUI, which yields the desired result. Now I like to perform that exact same operation on the very same data in a Python script:
def BooleanDifference():
    filter = Rhino.DocObjects.ObjectType.AnyObject

    rc, mesh1 = Rhino.Input.RhinoGet.GetOneObject("Select mesh to subtract from", False, filter)
    if rc != Rhino.Commands.Result.Success: return rc
    if not mesh1: return Rhino.Commands.Result.Failure

    rc, mesh2 = Rhino.Input.RhinoGet.GetOneObject("Select mesh to subtract", False, filter)
    if rc != Rhino.Commands.Result.Success: return rc
    if not mesh2: return Rhino.Commands.Result.Failure

    tolerance = scriptcontext.doc.ModelAbsoluteTolerance
    rc, dub = Rhino.Geometry.Mesh.CreateBooleanDifference(mesh1, mesh2, tolerance)
    if rc != Rhino.Commands.Result.Success: return rc
    if not dub: return Rhino.Commands.Result.Failure

    scriptcontext.doc.Views.Redraw()
    return Rhino.Commands.Result.Success

The function CreateBooleanDifference refuses to execute, presumably because I fail to capture or type-cast the mesh object reference correctly into IEnumerables before I hand them into the difference function (NB: the selected objects are valid solid meshes in the first place).
The error message is:
TypeError: Rhino.DocObjects.ObjRef value cannot be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Rhino.Geometry.Mesh] in method Rhino.Geometry.Mesh[] CreateBooleanDifference(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Rhino.Geometry.Mesh], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Rhino.Geometry.Mesh], Rhino.Geometry.MeshBooleanOptions, Rhino.Commands.Result ByRef)

So how would I do that?

To perform a boolean difference on two mesh objects in Rhino using Python, you need to convert objects of type Rhino.DocObjects.ObjRef to Rhino.Geometry.Mesh

Thanks. Would you mind dropping a line of code of how I would do the type cast in my context?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I found it out myself.
First you need to extract the Mesh from the object reference and stick into a list/IEnumerable container (below only for first mesh):
rc, mesh1 = Rhino.Input.RhinoGet.GetOneObject("Select mesh to subtract from", False, filter)
mesh1_  = []
mesh1_.append(mesh1.Mesh())

Then you need to construct the tolerance as a proper object:
tolerance = Rhino.Geometry.MeshBooleanOptions()
tolerance.Tolerance = scriptcontext.doc.ModelAbsoluteTolerance

This and above IEnumerables you then can stick into the boolean difference and add the resulting list of meshes to the document:
dub, rc = Rhino.Geometry.Mesh.CreateBooleanDifference(mesh1_, mesh2_, tolerance)

for m in dub:
    scriptcontext.doc.Objects.AddMesh(m)

Last remove the input meshes and redraw the document:
scriptcontext.doc.Objects.Delete(mesh1.Object())
scriptcontext.doc.Objects.Delete(mesh2.Object())

scriptcontext.doc.Views.Redraw()

For sake of brevity I ommitted all tests if the execution went fine and wrapping function (see original question).
